# Insert value of radio button with variable name in database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to insert the answers of my quiz application in the database. I am using Codeigniter. The quiz questions are randomly generated. 10 questions are shown to the user. The following is my code:

The view

```
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
            <?php 
            $i = 1;            
            echo form_open('Menu/submit_ans', array('name' => 'quiz'));
            foreach ($quiz_array as $q){
            ?>    
            <td colspan="2"style="background-color: #337ab7;color:white;"> <h4>Question No. <?php echo $i?> </h4></td>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php echo $q->ques;?></td>
            <input hidden name="qid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $q->qid;?>">
            <input hidden name="uid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_1;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_2;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_3;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $q->ans_4;?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="4"></td>
            </tr>


            <?php 
                $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <center><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit!</button></a></center>
    </div>
            <?php echo form_close();?>
```

The Controller:

```
function submit_ans(){
    $data = array(
    $q_array = $_POST['qid'],
    $u_array = $_POST['uid'],
    $ans_array = $_POST['ans']
    );
    $this->load->model('MyModel');
    $this->MyModel->insert_ans($data);
}
```

The Model

function insert_ans($data){

```
foreach($data as $answer) {
    var_dump($answer);

    }

}
```

The vardump result

//for question id

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => string '12' (length=2)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '6' (length=1)
  4 => string '11' (length=2)
  5 => string '7' (length=1)
  6 => string '10' (length=2)
  7 => string '2' (length=1)
  8 => string '8' (length=1)
  9 => string '1' (length=1)
  10 => string '5' (length=1)
  11 => string '9' (length=1)
```

//for user id

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '1' (length=1)
  6 => string '1' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => string '1' (length=1)
  9 => string '1' (length=1)
  10 => string '1' (length=1)
  11 => string '1' (length=1)
```

//for answers

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => string '2' (length=1)
  5 => string '2' (length=1)
  6 => string '3' (length=1)
  7 => string '3' (length=1)
  8 => string '4' (length=1)
  9 => string '3' (length=1)
  10 => string '2' (length=1)
  11 => string '3' (length=1)
```

I am getting all the results that I want from question ID to answers. How can I insert this table in the database now?

Following is my table made up of 4 columns:

ans_id - auto incremental
user_id - user who answers the questions 
q_id - the question answered
ans_att - the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the radio name as a array:

```
<input type="radio" name="asw[]" value="1"></td>
<input type="radio" name="asw[]" value="1"></td>
```

and, for include in your db, try this php:

```
$asw = $_POST['asw'];

foreach($asw as $answer){
mysql_query("insert into table_name (col_name) values ('". $aswer ."')");
}
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a random name, because this last gonna be inserted to your data so you can try fix name ,random values and id. Try this one with java script function
" type="radio" name="as" value="">
but could you please give us your table to be more clear

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer